# Create a new object from pointer reference C++

Tags: c++, qt

So, I've this code below:

```
 foreach (QLineSeries* series, lineSeriesMap.values())
    {
        // ...
    }
```

And I will modify series objects in this loop and I don't want to modify the original one, but create a new edited one. I'm extremely new to C++ and Qt so, I want something as the Java code below:

```
QLineSeries editedSeries = new QLineSeries(series);
```

I'm deleting elements, editing and re-ordering them from series by the way. But, as I said I need them both.

**EDIT:**

I've tried your answers but best way I believe is putting the code. This is a project made by some co-worker who changed jobs so its not my code, as i said I dont know C++.

> chartwidget.h

```
void fillAreaSeries();
//...
QHash<QString,QLineSeries*> lineSeriesEntersMap;
QHash<QString,QLineSeries*> lineSeriesExitsMap;
```

> chartwidget.cpp

```
void ChartWidget::fillAreaSeries() {
foreach (QLineSeries* seriesEnter, lineSeriesEntersMap.values())
    {
        if (lineSeriesExitsMap.contains(seriesEnter->name())) {
            QLineSeries* seriesExit = lineSeriesExitsMap.value(seriesEnter->name());
            if (!((seriesEnter->points().size() == 1) && (seriesExit->points().size() == 1))) {
                for(int i = seriesEnter->points().size() - 1; i > 0; i--)
                    {
                        if (seriesEnter->points().at(i - 1).y() > seriesEnter->points().at(i).y())
                        {
                            seriesEnter->removePoints(i, 1);
                        }
                    }
                        for (int i = seriesExit->points().size() - 1; i > 0; i--)
                    {
                        if (seriesExit->points().at(i - 1).y() < seriesExit->points().at(i).y())
                        {
                            seriesExit->removePoints(i-1, 1);
                        }
                    }

                    QVector<QPointF> editPoints = seriesExit->pointsVector();
                    std::sort(editPoints.begin(),editPoints.end(), [] (const QPointF & p1, const QPointF & p2)
                    {
                        return p1.y() < p2.y();
                    });
                    seriesExit->replace(editPoints);

                    qDebug() << "__Swap:__";
                    qDebug() << seriesEnter->points().at(0).y();
                    qDebug() << seriesExit->points().at(0).y();
                    qDebug() << seriesEnter->points().at(1).y();
                    qDebug() << seriesExit->points().at(1).y();

                    QAreaSeries* series = new QAreaSeries(seriesEnter, seriesExit);
                    series->setName(seriesEnter->name());


                    series->setOpacity(0.50);
                    series->setPen(Qt::NoPen);
                    series->setPointLabelsFormat(seriesEnter->name().split("-").at(0));
                    areaSeriesMap.insert(series->name(), series);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit 3:**
So, QLineSeries contains QPointF list. I've the code below:

```
foreach (QLineSeries* seriesEnter, lineSeriesEntersMap.values())
    {
  QLineSeries* entersToBeEdited = new QLineSeries(chart);
entersToBeEdited->setName(seriesEnter->name());
entersToBeEdited->points().append(seriesEnter->points());
//...
```

append doesnt work and returns 0 points. But I can set a name. I also tried appending by looping through items and adding it by

`entersToBeEdited->points().push_back(seriesEnter->points().at(i));`

and still nothing. I also tried `<<` and `+=` but no luck.

Comment: in constrast to java, in c++ not everything is a reference. You dont have a pointer reference, but just a pointer. Anyhow, what happened when you tried that line of code?

Comment: Please do include the error message in the quesiton and if possible provide a [mcve]

Comment: @user463035818 it forces(by giving an error) me to use a pointer and that pointer also applies (by that pointer I mean `*editedSeries`)  and `gives Qt5Charts.dll Access violation reading location`

Comment: what kind of object is LineSeriesMap ? is it `QList<LineSeries*>` ? if so you can use iterator like that : `LineSeries *currentSeries; QList<LineSeries*>::iterator it; for(it=lineseriesmap.begin(); it<lineseriesmap.end();++it){ currentSeries = *it; }`

Comment: @user463035818 I've edited the question.

Comment: @user2019716 yes you're right. I put down header definition to question

Comment: entersToBeEdited->points().append(seriesEnter->points()); will have no effect since points() returns a copy of the points list and not the original one (return by value).
This is aimed at protecting the object content from accidental modification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the class definition of QLineSeries, I don't see any simple way to copy your instance in order to duplicate it.
Thus you will have first to create a new instance :
`QLineSeries editedSeries;`
and manually copy the content of your original series in it.
`editedSeries.append(originalSeries.points());`
As you cannot modify the data once it is in the `QLineSeries` object, I would recommend to subclass `QLineSeries` or modify the `QList<QPointF>` obtained via `originalSeries.points()` before adding it to your new chart.

Comment: I've tried as you said but when I define editedSeries as `QLineSeries editedSeries` it gives error when I define QAreaSeries (I've added code to question) if I define editedSeries as `QLineSeries*` it gives access violation

Comment: okay so I did it as QLineSeries* but that doesnt add points sadly.

Comment: have you tried `entersToBeEdited->append()` instead of `entersToBeEdited->points()->append()` ? points() returns a value not a reference or a pointer, so modifying it will have no effect on the object content.

Answer (score 0):

`QLineSeries` is not copyable, so you can't do what you want by modifying a copy. You will need to create a new `QLineSeries` from scratch.

Comment: How can I do that because of all this pointer shenanigans I'm not sure how to achieve that